# Gradle tool in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I defined a Jenkins Declarative pipeline to CI/CD my project. I am using gradle as my build tool. However I don't want to use the Gradle Wrapper and check it int the VCS. So I planed on using the jenkins tools functionality as below so that I can update the version number if I need to in future. But it doesn't seem to work.

pipeline {
    agent any

```
tools {
     gradle "gradle-4.0"
}

stage("Compile") {
    steps {
        sh 'gradle project/build.gradle classes'
    }
}
```

I get the error "script.sh: gradle: not found".

I tried to echo PATH and that doesn't contain the path of this autoinstalled gradle tool. Please help.

Comment: I could not figure out why the PATH is not set. I am just using jenkins script pipeline instead of declarative as a workaround for this issue.

    `env.GRADLE="${tool 'gradle-4.0'}"
     env.PATH="${env.GRADLE}/bin:${env.PATH}"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue on the gradle plugin for Jenkins on plugin version 1.26. Please see the link to the bug reported below.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42381